# setSelection in spinner and updating data in parse

Tags: android, parsing, fragment, android-spinner

I have a problem with updating parse data .i used this code but nothing changed .

Did i miss something important ? i see some codes using object id but i did not understand it . here is My code :

```
  saveEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        query.whereEqualTo("TaskN", strtext2);
        query.whereEqualTo("TheUser", currentUser);
        query.getInBackground(ob ,new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {


            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
               if (e == null){
                  // String ob= object.getObjectId();
                    object.put("TaskN", taskNAME.getText().toString());
                    object.put("Email", emailNAme.getText().toString());
                    object.put("TheUser", currentUser);
                    object.put("Note", note.getText().toString());
                    object.saveInBackground(); // save what we do

                    // object.put("Name", oldname);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sucssfully Changed",         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
               else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Nothing Changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                Fragment frag;
                FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                frag = new AllTaskFragment();
                AllTaskFragment llf = new AllTaskFragment();
                ft.replace(R.id.fofo, frag);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);

                ft.commit();

            }
        });






    }

});
```

Also the setSelection does not work with me , i want to retreive the string data from parse then set the spinner to the correct position but it always get first position , here is my code :

```
final Spinner spinner=(Spinner) rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.country_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
Cancel=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cancelbutton);

query.whereEqualTo("TaskN",strtext2);
```

query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback() {

```
   public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
       String email = object.getString("Email");
       String Note = object.getString("Note");
       String taskname = object.getString("TaskN");
       String qnumber = object.getString("Quadric");


       if (qnumber == "q1"){                   //spinner.setSelection(0,true);
          spinner.setSelection(0);
       }
       else if (qnumber == "q2"){
           spinner.setSelection(1,false);}
       else if (qnumber == "q3"){
           spinner.setSelection(2,false);}
       else if (qnumber == "q4"){
           spinner.setSelection(3,false);}
```

Comment: What's "ob" here: _query.getInBackground(ob ,new GetCallback<ParseObject>()_ ? Try to add a CallBack function in: **object.saveInBackground()** to get the error message.

Comment: ob is the object , i was trying to retreive the object id .

Comment: is only you get the objectId from a query in _Users and put in the field. Please, get the error message and paste here.